# How to define file-local substitution directives?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I would like to factor some part of the documentation, where a single value changes from one file to another. Suppose I have three files, `common.rst.inc`, `foo.rst` and `bar.rst`:

In `common.rst.inc`:

```
text |this| text
```

In `foo.rst`:

```
.. |this| replace:: Foo
.. include:: common.rst.inc
```

In `bar.rst`:

```
.. |this| replace:: Bar
.. include:: common.rst.inc
```

However, building with sphinx-build 1.3.6 leads to:

```
ERROR: Duplicate substitution definition name: "this".
```

Is there a way to do what I'd like, or some alternative approach?

Comment: reStructuredText is a markup language, not a programming language, so you cannot use programming logic in .rst itself. You will need to declare unique variables or replacement values.

Comment: @StevePiercy Thanks. I am trying to see what my options are. When you say unique variables, are you talking about the Python side, like the configuration file or an extension? I guess I could have a couple of custom directives which respectively set and get a property for a key (ie. a dict).

Comment: Scratch the variable concept. I was thinking of passing them into Jinja2 templates in a theme, but that is outside the scope of reStructuredText markup and wouldn't be applied in the included .rst file. So unique substitutions are your only option, AFAIK.